# Get items from list where index in ()

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a list of `CustomClassItem`. I have several ints which are the indexes of the items I want to retrieve.

What is the quickest / most efficient way to get them? Something in the spirit of the index operator with more than one index or maybe `myList.GetWhereIndexIs(myIntsList)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use Linq:

```
List<CustomClassItem> items = myIntsList.Select(i => myList[i]).ToList();
```

Make sure that `myIntsList.All(i => i >= 0 && i < myList.Count);`

Edit:

If an index doesn't exist in the list, ignore this index:

```
List<CustomClassItem> items = myIntsList.Where(i => i >= 0 && i < myList.Count)
                                        .Select(i => myList[i]).ToList();
```

Comment: Assuming that index position exists.

Comment: @G.Abitbol what Bob said is correct.  You have to explicitly decide what to do when an index isn't present.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl I added an example that ignores invalid indices (in case that that's what's intended).

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I think your answer is great, it's pretty much impossible for you to know what the right behavior is for his situation. He might want a null there, or he might want them filtered, or he might...there's no point "solving" that for him.

Answer (score 5):

I think a nice and efficient solution would be to use `yield` in combination with an extension method:

```
public static IList<T> SelectByIndex<T>(this IList<T> src, IEnumerable<int> indices)
{
    foreach (var index in indices) {
        yield return src[index];
    }
}
```

Now you can do: `myList.SelectByIndex(new [] { 0, 1, 4 });`

You could also use a params object:

```
public static IList<T> SelectByIndexParams<T>(this IList<T> src, params int[] indices)
{
    foreach (var index in indices) {
        yield return src[index];
    }
}
```

Now you can do: `myList.SelectByIndexParams(0, 1, 4);`

Answer (score 2):

What you want (if I'm reading correctly) is the following:

```
var indices = [ 1, 5, 7, 9 ];
list.Where((obj, ind) => indices.Contains(ind)).ToList();
```

That will give you a `List<CustomClassItem>` containing all those items whose indices are in your list.

Almost all of the LINQ extension methods accept a function taking a T *and* an int, that is the index of T in the Enumerable.  It's really handy.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var result = myList.Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
    .Join(indices, x => x.Index, index => index, (x, index) => x.Item);
```

More efficient and safe(ensures that the indices exist) but less readable than other approaches.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/p3WE4q)

Perhaps you want to create an extension which increases readability and reusability:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetIndices<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inputSequence, IEnumerable<int> indices)
{
    var items = inputSequence.Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
       .Join(indices, x => x.Index, index => index, (x, index) => x.Item);
    foreach (T item in items)
        yield return item;
}
```

Then you could use it in this way:

```
var indices = new[]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var first5 = myList.GetIndices(indices).Take(5);
```

Used `Take` to demonstrate that linq's deferred execution still works here.